# Passing a string to a DBLookupComboBox

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I'm getting an access violation when passing a string to a DBLookupComboBox in Delphi XE6.  The `BusName` is a string containing a Company Name coming from the Orders Form.  Am I using the right control for this?

Here's some information about the DBLookupComboBox setup.

`KeyField` is called `CustID`
`ListField` is called `CompanyName`
`ListSource` is called `CustNames`

```
CustNameDBLCBox.Field.AsString:= OrdersForm.BusName;
```

Not sure what I'm missing?

Comment: Update: When on a customer order form quoting an order estimate to a caller.  When the caller says they would like to schedule order, user clicks an order button, which grabs some data (ie, customer name, address info), closes the form and then opens the new service form to place the order.  This is where I have a DBLookupComboBox.  Since we already know the customers name from the customer order form, I'd like the name to appear in the DBLookupComboBox.  So I'm passing the BusName (string - Company name) coming from Orders Form to the DBLookupComboBox. Is this the way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DBLookupCombobox` can be used for two different purposes.
The usual would be having assigned  `Datasource` and `Datafield` to use it to change/display a field of one datafield with the data from a lookupdataset.
Every manual change in the DBLookupCombobox would set the Datafield to the Value of the KeyField and any change in the Dataset bound via Datasource will change the displayed value using the Listfield value found by the KeyField in the Dataset defined by ListSource.

The other usage of DBLookupCombobox would be to use it without binding on Datasource/Datafield just for selecting a Value and using the Keyvalue or Text for further work.

**TL;DR**
Here are two reasons which can cause then access violation:

1. OrdersForm is not assigned any more (maybe freed on close)
2. You did not assign Datasource / Datafield but you are trying to set 
   `CustNameDBLCBox.Field.AsString := <sometext>` which will lead to an access violation as described by you, since Field is not assigned: `property Field: TField read FDataField;`
   If you would have assigned Datasource / Datafield you might have got an error pointing to an invalid value for your Datafield something like Integer <> String, but not an access violation.

To change the displayed value you will have to change the KeyValue:

```
  if CustNameDBLCBox.ListSource.DataSet.Locate(CustNameDBLCBox.ListField, OrdersForm.BusName ,[]) then
      CustNameDBLCBox.KeyValue := CustNameDBLCBox.ListSource.DataSet.FieldByName(CustNameDBLCBox.KeyField).Value;
```